# When I am creating a dictionary for German Language , I am facing some problems in making tokens

Tags: python-2.7, deep-learning

I am using sublime text editor for coding.

**code:**

```
# coding: utf-8
import nltk
line = "Frau Präsidentin, zu Recht befaßt sich das Parlament regelmäßig mit der Verkehrssicherheit."
print nltk.word_tokenize(line.decode('utf8'))
```

**result:**

```
[u'Frau', u'Pr', u'\xe4', u'sidentin', u',', u'zu', u'Recht', u'befa', u'\xdf', u't', u'sich', u'das', u'Parlament', u'regelm', u'\xe4', u'\xdf', u'ig', u'mit', u'der', u'Verkehrssicherheit', u'.']
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Still tokens are not correct.
because its breaking Präsidentin into sub token which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=word_tokenize#module-nltk.tokenize):

> This particular tokenizer requires the Punkt sentence tokenization models to be installed.

I'm guessing you need these, they include a German Model.
Instructions for installing these can be found at http://www.nltk.org/data.html, or the models can be directly downloaded from [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip)

Answer (score 0):

This worked correct for him.

```
# coding: utf-8
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize

line = "Frau Präsidentin, zu Recht befaßt sich das Parlament regelmäßig mit der Verkehrssicherheit."
print wordpunct_tokenize(line.decode("utf8"))

result:
[u'Frau', u'Pr\xe4sidentin', u',', u'zu', u'Recht', u'befa\xdft', u'sich', u'das', u'Parlament', u'regelm\xe4\xdfig', u'mit', u'der', u'Verkehrssicherheit', u'.']
[Finished in 0.5s]
```